# Leaky Roof after new shingles were installed

Tags: roof

I live in an 'old' house that was not very well cared for. The original home was built in 1910 and has had several add ons that do not make sense with the roofs to prove it. The original house has a 10/12 pitch and the other roofs vary from hip in the back of the house, and then a dormer in the front with an open deck upstairs that I never use, and then another silly roof that does not make any sense why it was even built.

I just had new asphalt shingles layed over the existing roll roofing that the last roofer 'fixed' and sealed. The roof portion that was shingled is over the upstairs bathroom which when it has rained in the past, flooded the bathroom and then the water ended up in the ceiling of the downstairs bathroom. So, now I have two bathrooms that need to be gutted and sheetrocked and possibly new subfloor and tile. Anyway, I just got the roof done last week and it rained yesterday; the bathroom leaked AGAIN! Not very much but I could see that a couple of rafters had water dripping. I got about a half cup of water.

There is another roof that is higher than this roof. Do you suppose the leak is coming from the roof that was not shingled? I'm just glad that I did not install the sheetrock just yet. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Complain to the roofer, the work should have a warranty of some type. If it is the other roof it would be in his benefit to point that out and suggest replacing it. If it is in the replaced roof he should repair it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you document the problem by sending a certified letter to the roofer, photographing the leaks and using a felt tip pen to outline the areas and dating the lines. I’d keep this in a journal and up date the journal on a regular basis… say every 2 weeks to a month, depending on the amount of rain and damage.

In your letter, I’d give the roofer 1 week to come find and fix the leak or you’ll try to find the leak and hire another roofer to fix it…and recoup the cost from them.

Then, if you have to find the leak, I’d get a garden hose and start near the bottom of the roof spraying up under the shingles, edges of roof, etc. until it starts to leak in each documented area. (You’ll need someone inside looking for leaks while you spray.)

I’d also check with your local Building Department and see if they need a Building Permit. If so, ask them if he has one.

I’d also check to see if they are licensed to do this type of work (roofing).

You’ll need an attorney experienced in construction law. Or some licensing agencies have committees that can review your case and make a determination as to what happened and who pays. (They also hold a bond from the roofer so if they determine he is at fault, then they can take their bond and give you the money.)